# Match PHP global variable between other globals

Tags: php, regex, global-variables

I'm attempting to parse through my project files containing globals, some of which have multiple global variables to them.

Example:

```
global $ID, $NR, $USER; 
global $NR;
```

I will find only the `$NR` variable between them.

My RegEx:

```
global[?\w+($NR)+\s+?]
```

This find a lot of globals, but not $NR. What's wrong?

Comment: [Does it really find anything](https://regex101.com/r/pC7oK5/1)?

Comment: [`^\s*global\s*\$\w+(?:,\s*\$\w+)*;$`](https://regex101.com/r/wK2hB2/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This will find all globals without $NR

Comment: @Tushar This works! If you post this as answer, I will mark this als solution.

Comment: *What's wrong*: the `[?\w+($NR)+\s+?]` matches 1 character, either a `?`, word char, `+`, `(`, `$`, `N`, `R`, `)` or whitespace. It **won't** find anything other than `global` in the above sample text.

Comment: @Tushar: You actually can add your answer since it worked for OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^\s*global\s*\$\w+(?:,\s*\$\w+)*;$
```

This RegEx will capture all the globals irrespective of multiple variable declarations or single.

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `^`: Start of the line
2. `\s*`: Zero or more spaces
3. `global`: Match the exact string *global*
4. `\$`: Matches the `$` symbol. As `$` have different meaning in RegEx, it need to escape by preceding with backslash to match literally.
5. `\w+`: Matches one or more alphanumberic and `_` characters. `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
6. `(?:,\s*\$\w+)*`

   - `(?:...)`: Non capturging group
   - `,`: Match `,` symbol
   - `\s*`: Match zero or more space characters
   - `(...)*`: Match the group zero or more times.
7. `;`: Match `;` symbol
8. `$`: End of line

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wK2hB2/1)

Adding RegEx Railroad Diagram for better understanding.

[image: RegEx Railroad Diagram]

**Note:** If there are trailing spaces after semicolon, add `\s*` after semicolon and before `$`.

Comment: How did you generate the Railroad Diagram?

Comment: @PatrickMlr [Atom RegEx Railroad Diagram Plugin](https://atom.io/packages/regex-railroad-diagram). You can create [online too](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5Cs*global%5Cs*%5C%24%5Cw%2B(%3F%3A%2C%5Cs*%5C%24%5Cw%2B)*%3B%24).